# Отображение heatmap вместе с границами региона html

Tags: html

Есть некий датафрейм, по которому пробегаюсь и строю границы регионов на карте. Хочу еще добавить слой с heatmap для каждого региона. Как это седалть? То, что сейчас, не работает

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Heatmap</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
      <style>
        #map {
          height: 800px;
          width: 100%;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <label for="citySelect">Выбор региона:</label>
      <select id="regionSelect" name="region">
        {% for region in regions %}
        <option value="{{ region }}">{{ region }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    
      <div id="map"></div>
    
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet.heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js"></script>
      <script>
        var map;
        var data = {{ data|tojson }};
        var geojsonLayer;
        // var heatL;
    
       async function updateMap(selectedRegion) {
         var filteredData = data.filter(function (item) {
           return item["ФИАС Регион"] === selectedRegion;
         });
    
         var heatmapData = filteredData.map(function(item) {
             return [parseFloat(item.latitude), parseFloat(item.longitude), parseFloat(item["Страховая сумма Кумуляция"])];
           });
    
         // heatL = L.heatLayer(heatmapData, {
         //     gradient: { 0.1: 'blue', 0.3: 'lime', 0.5: 'yellow', 0.7: 'orange', 1: 'red' },
         //     radius: 8
         // }).addTo(map);
         // }
    
         try {
           const response = await fetch(`https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q=${selectedRegion}&polygon_geojson=1`);
           const data = await response.json();
           if (data.length > 0 && data[0].geojson) {
             if (geojsonLayer) {
               map.removeLayer(geojsonLayer);
             }
             geojsonLayer = L.geoJSON(data[0].geojson).addTo(map);
             map.fitBounds(geojsonLayer.getBounds());
           }
         } catch (error) {
           console.error('Error fetching region data:', error);
         }
       }
    
        function initMap() {
          map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 2);
          L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          }).addTo(map);
          updateMap(document.getElementById("regionSelect").value);
        }
    
        document.getElementById("regionSelect").addEventListener("change", function() {
          updateMap(this.value);
        });
    
      </script>
      <script>initMap();</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```